# Convert this function from childhood times to something better?

Tags: javascript

I needed to show some simple code example for friend, for example moving a button along the edge of the screen clockwise. Sure this is something very simple, no, this is simplest. But I found myself spending about almost 30 minutes on that. I was embarased, because I am professional programmer for 20+ years, and I even needed to start the program many times before the button was flying the right ways. And I was thinking, why? So I speculated that this kind of code is difficult to get right immediately, because it is very old style, each case is typed separately, each check must be entered manually, you need to go through each iteration and make carefully sure that all numbers and checks are exactly precisely correct, and this is hard to do because of the nature of code style, which is, eehh, spaghetti, messy?

So I was like, is there a way to convert it to "modern" way, like use loop instead of cases, use templates or other meta-programming, use functional approach or at least use arrays. And it seems I cannot find any good way for this.

```
var mx = screen.width - b.w, my = screen.height - b.h

setInterval(function() {
    var step = 3
    if (state == 1) {
        b.x += step
        if (b.x >= mx) b.x = mx, state++
    } else if (state == 2) {
        b.y += step
        if (b.y >= my) b.y = my, state++
    } else if (state == 3) {
        b.x -= step
        if (b.x <= 0) b.x = 0, state++
    } else if (state == 4) {
        b.y -= step
        if (b.y <= 0) b.y = 0, state = 1
    }
    b.apply()
}, 1)
```

This is JavaScript, in C it would be even more difficult to get right fast, because you need to think about types.

Here is what I come up myself... This maybe demonstrating what I am trying to achieve. I am not talking about choosing different algorithm. but rather abotu exploring language(s) features, and programming techniques.

```
var D = 3, name = ['x','y'], delta = [D,D,-D,-D], 
    limit = [screen.width - b.w, screen.height - b.h,0,0]

setInterval(function() {
    b[name[0]] += delta[0]
    if (delta[0] > 0 && b[name[0]] > limit[0] || b[name[0]] <= 0)
        b[name[0]] = limit[0],
        [name,delta,limit].some(function(x){ x.push(x.shift()) })
    b.apply()
},1)
```

This one at least separates data from code, making it simpler to get it right. It worked for me from the first attempt. But I am still not satisfied completely)

Comment: I'd wager it worked the first time because you already had the algorithm figured out with the first one.  Which one did your friend consider better?

Answer (score 3):

The average American newspaper article is written at something like a 6th grade reading level.  This isn't because the person writing it never went beyond 6th grade; rather, they've learned that it's better to write in a manner that everyone can understand.  I bring this up because you're calling your code childish or unsophisticated, yet it's the most clear and concise code there is for the task you had, and therefore the best.

If you want to go around a square, you're really not going to have any choice besides what you did - have four different directions to go, and keep track of where you're at.  You code shows off the basics of a state machine, because that's what you need to go around in four different straight lines.

If you're willing to fake it with a slightly different movement, you can remove all states and just go around in an ellipse using some trigonometry.  (It actually should be a circle, but since the screen is rectangular, you'll get an ellipse, with different speeds on the long and short sides of the screen.)

Here's the basics.  It may need some tweaking to make sure you have the edges hitting the right spot.  Truthfully, I think by the time you work out the special cases on this version, you'll find your solution was more elegant.

```
// find the center x and y
var centerX = screen.width / 2;
var centerY = screen.height / 2;
// first, find the radius.  If you want to cover everything, you need half the diagonal
var radius = Math.sqrt(centerX * centerX + centerY * centerY);
var increment = 0.01; // higher values, of course, will move you faster
var theta = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    b.x = Math.min(Math.max(centerX + radius * Math.cos(x), screen.width), 0);
    b.y = Math.min(Math.max(centerY + radius * Math.sin(y), screen.height), 0);
    theta -= increment;
    b.apply();
}, 1);
```

As I mentioned, this will almost certainly need some tweaking to come anywhere as close to looking good as the code you made.  My code may be less childish, but it's less easy to understand - and it actually does less well at accomplishing your task.

Don't worry about how fancy your code was.  It works well, and is clear to understand, and that's really what matters.

#### Edit

I realized later on that I forgot to base everything from the center, and the code I had posted would do a circle from the top left.  I've added in the center stuff above.  See?  Adding complexity doesn't at all imply the code will be better... :-)

Also, I did figure out one change I would recommend to your original algorithm:  name your states!  Make them strings, and have state be "top", "right", "bottom" and "left", and actively set them rather than using state++.  That will help make your code even more readable.